# C segmentation fault (core dumped) function

Tags: c

I believe it has something to do with my use of `roll_die`. If I just use `rand()%6+1` instead of `roll_die` in the body it works, but I want to use the function. Also, would there be any way to use less lines to print the results to make my code shorter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int roll_die() {
    return 1 + rand() % 6;
}

int main()
{

srand((unsigned) time(0));

int roll_die;
int first_die_roll, second_die_roll, total;
int roll_result[13] = {0};
int count = 36000; 
while(count--) {

     first_die_roll = roll_die;
     second_die_roll = roll_die;
     total = first_die_roll + second_die_roll;

    roll_result[total]++;

   }

   printf("Computed die rolling frequencies for 36,000 rolls:\n");

   printf("Sum = 2; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[2], (float)roll_result[2]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 3; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[3], (float)roll_result[3]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 4; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[4], (float)roll_result[4]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 5; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[5], (float)roll_result[5]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 6; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[6], (float)roll_result[6]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 7; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[7], (float)roll_result[7]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 8; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[8], (float)roll_result[8]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 9; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[9], (float)roll_result[9]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 10; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[10], (float)roll_result[10]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 11; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[11], (float)roll_result[11]/36000 * 100, '%');

   printf("Sum = 12; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%c\n", roll_result[12], (float)roll_result[12]/36000 * 100, '%');

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you want to call a function, use `roll_die()` not `roll_die`.  `int roll_die` means you're using uninitialized memory and you can remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration `int roll_die;` inside `main` declares `roll_die` as a **local** `int` variable, and hides (or [*shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) the function with the same name. Thus, when you later have a line such as this:

```c
    first_die_roll = roll_die; // Copying a local variable
```

you are assigning to `first_die_roll` the value of the ***unitialized*** local variable. Thus, the calulated value of `total` is undefined, and the reference to the `roll_result[total]` array element will very likely be 'out of bounds', causing a memory access error (= "segmentation fault").

Fix: First, remove the declaration of the local variable; then, to invoke the `roll_die` function, you will need to add parentheses to the name, wherever you need it:

```c
//  int roll_die; // Remove this line - it HIDES your "roll_die" function!
//...

    first_die_roll = roll_die(); // Brackets make this a function call.
    second_die_roll = roll_die();
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a local variable: `int roll_die` that masks the definition of the *function* `roll_die`.

Also, you can *not* call the function [or any function] just by giving its name. When you just specify the function, this is the *address* of the function itself, and *not* an invocation/call of the function.

Thus, instead of:

```
first_die_roll = roll_die;
```

You want:

```
first_die_roll = roll_die();
```

And, you can use a `for` loop for printing. Also, you can add a literal `%` in the format with `%%`.

Anyway, here's your code fixed and annotated with the bugs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROLLMAX     13

int
roll_die(void)
{
    return 1 + rand() % 6;
}

int
main()
{

    srand((unsigned) time(0));

// NOTE/BUG: this shadows/masks the actual function
#if 0
    int roll_die;
#endif

    int first_die_roll, second_die_roll, total;
    int roll_result[ROLLMAX] = { 0 };
    int count = 36000;

    while (count--) {
// NOTE/BUG: this does _not_ call roll_die -- it merely sets the values to the
// address of the roll_die function
#if 0
        first_die_roll = roll_die;
        second_die_roll = roll_die;
#else
        first_die_roll = roll_die();
        second_die_roll = roll_die();
#endif
        total = first_die_roll + second_die_roll;

        roll_result[total]++;
    }

    printf("Computed die rolling frequencies for 36,000 rolls:\n");

    for (total = 2;  total < ROLLMAX;  ++total) {
        int result = roll_result[total];
        printf("Sum = %d; Frequency = %d ; Percentage = %f%%\n",
            total, result, (float) result / 36000 * 100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```